# ValueError: unsupported format character ']' (0x5d)

Tags: python, bots, irc

I'm trying to make irc bot with python. The bot will parse XML and paste its content on channel. This is part of my code

```
f = open("1.xml")
data = f.read()
f.close()
domi = parseString(data)
attackerbartag = domi.getElementsByTagName('bar')[0].toxml()
attackerbar = attackerbartag.replace('<bar>','').replace('</bar>','')
attackerbar = round(float(attackerbar)2)
defenderbar = 100 - attackerbar

attackertag = domi.getElementsByTagName('name')[1].toxml()
attacker = attackertag.replace('<name>','').replace('</name>','')

defendertag = domi.getElementsByTagName('name')[42].toxml()
defender = defendertag.replace('<name>','').replace('</name>','')

attackerpointtag = domi.getElementsByTagName('points')[1].toxml()
attackerpoint = attackerpointtag.replace('<points>','').replace('</points>','')

defenderpointtag = domi.getElementsByTagName('points')[6].toxml()
defenderpoint = defenderpointtag.replace('<points>','').replace('</points>','')

attackerdomtag = domi.getElementsByTagName('domination')[0].toxml()
attackerdom = attackerdomtag.replace('<domination>','').replace('</domination>','')

defenderdomtag = domi.getElementsByTagName('domination')[4].toxml()
defenderdom = defenderdomtag.replace('<domination>','').replace('</domination>','')

result = 'Div.1 :: %s [ %s p ] [ %s% ] [ %s Dom ] <--> [ %s Dom ] [ %s% ] [ %s p ] %s ::' % (attacker, attackerpoint, attackerbar, attackerdom, defenderdom, defenderbar, defenderpoint, defender)
return result
```

and I got `ValueError: unsupported format character ']' (0x5d).`

I'm pretty sure I already close all [ ]

I tried change [ ] with () and the error is `ValueError: unsupported format character ')' (0x5d)`

Can anyone show me where I made a boo boo ?
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps use a real xml parser?

Comment: Check the spelling of `defender`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've twice put `[ %s% ]`, which includes an extra % after the `s`. Python interprets that as `%]`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

You have two `%` characters in there that are not meant to be formatting characters. You need to double it to make Python ignore it:

```
result = 'Div.1 :: %s [ %s p ] [ %s%% ] [ %s Dom ] <--> [ %s Dom ] [ %s%% ] [ %s p ] %s ::' % (attacker, attackerpoint, attackerbar, attackerdom, defenderdom, defenderbar, defenderpoint, defender)
```