# ValueError in Python: unsupported format character ']' (0x5d)

Tags: python

QUESTION: Same Error as this
[ValueError: unsupported format character ']' (0x5d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586544/valueerror-unsupported-format-character-0x5d/73539459#73539459)
but I can't seem to find any %

I am running a query in Python env using cur.execute()

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(f"""
   SELECT 
    FirstName,
    Surname,
   FORMAT(TotalHours / NULLIF((ContractHours - RemissionHours), 0) * 100, 'N2') AS [Utilisation %]

   FROM t
   JOIN Staff ON Staff.SID = t.SID

   WHERE (@IncludeLeavers = 'Yes' OR @IncludeLeavers= 'No' AND Staff.IsCurrent = 1)
   
   """,
        params={
          "IncludeLeavers": REPORT_OPTIONS["IncludeLeavers"][0]
        })
```

Error:

ValueError : unsupported format character ']' (0x5d) at index 511[' File "<'string'>",

on this line
`IncludeLeavers": REPORT_OPTIONS["IncludeLeavers"][0]`

To provide values to/ initialise the variable @IncludeLeavers, I have initialised it in Options, which need to match the query results.

[image: OPTIONS]

Comment: Could you provide some more context?  What function are you trying to run?  Some type of sql command?  I know '[' and ']' are reserved characters in sql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PatrickGorman Yes an sql query using pytds.connect & cur.execute(). The params is the 2nd part of the execute func. The query is finished before the start of the params definition so the reserved chars should still work, they do in other similar reports.

Comment: The issue is the percent character and `%]`  sequence. You'll need to escape the percent. See duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586544/valueerror-unsupported-format-character-0x5d?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://thewebdev.info/2022/04/15/how-to-selectively-escape-percent-in-python-strings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Sarah,

The issue is the percent character and %] sequence.

Adding another % wherever % was used, fixed the issue. Thanks Sarah.